# Injecting dependencies using an Interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Would it be technically a good and acceptable practice to inject required dependencies using an `Interceptor` type. For example:

```
public @interface Inject {
    public Class thisType();
}

public class InjectionInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public bool preHandle(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1, Object o) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) o;
        Class type = handlerMethod.getBeanType();
        Annotation[] annotations =  type.getAnnotationsByType(Inject.class);
        for(Annotation annotation: annotations){
            Inject inject = (inject) annotation;
            for(Field field :type.getDeclaredFields()){
                if(field.getType().equals(inject.thisType())){
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(handlerMethod.getBean(), Services.find(inject.thisType()));
                }
            }
            ....
      return true;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: What would we achieve with this kind of dependency injection?

Comment: And you want to do that in Spring wher you already have decend DI?? Why? You do know you can use `@Autowired` right?

Comment: @Antoniossss: Autowired is so useless, how can you tell on what type an interface must be bind and what if it has to be singleton or instantiated once per session.

Comment: @TusharBanne: Developing Per Session, Per Request, and Singleton binding

Comment: That you can achieve with scope in spring.

Comment: @TusharBanne: Yeah, I just found about that, but if you please provide me a proper example as an answer it will be both appreciated and accepted.

Comment: @Arrrr well you have proper scopes for that

Comment: @Arrr you have `@SessionScope` `@ReqestScope` `prototype` and default `@Singleton`. What would you need more?

Comment: @Antoniossss: I didn't know about these, but after posting this question and reading the comments everything was clarified and I learned how to use them. Thanks for mentioning those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bean can have 4 scopes.

1. Singleton
   Only one shared instance of the bean will be managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition will result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring container.

   It is default scope of a bean.
2. Prototype
   New instance is returned by the container when bean with the specified id is requested.

   Ex: If you have a bean with id as "employee" in your spring container, then everytime you do a

   `Employee emp = context.getBean("employee");`

   A new instance will be returned.

**request, session, and global session are for use only in web-based applications**

3. Request
   A new instance is created for every single HTTP request.
   Ex : Login needs different instance everytime.
4. Session
   A new instance will be created of the bean using the bean definition for the lifetime of a single HTTP Session.
5. global
   The global session scope is similar to the standard HTTP Session scope and really only makes sense in the context of portlet-based web applications

You can specify the scope of a bean in two ways

1. Using XML:

`<bean id="employee" class="com.company.Employee" scope="singleton"/>`

2. Using annotation.

   mark the class with `@Scope("prototype")`

you can read more about scopes [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

sample code for reference is available [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/)